# VBA User Form - Need it to copy formula from column F, 1 row above

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form I made for users to enter data. The data get's inserted into the next available row. That works well, but now I need the formula from the cell above in Column F to be copied into the new cell. Is there a code I could use this to work along with the copying of the input values to the sheet?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Method 2 is probably better suited for your purpose as it will adapt the cell references in the previous line to the next line.

**Method 1:** To set the formula of a cell, use

```
Sheets("sheet name").cells(row, column).Formula = ....
```

Row and column must be specified as integer values, I.e. For column F it would be 6. Assuming you have the number of the next free line in a variable called NextFreeLine:

```
Sheets("sheet name").cells(NextFreeLine, 6).Formula = Sheets("sheet name").cells(NextFreeLine-1, 6).Formula
```

**Method 2:** If you insist on literally copying the formula from somewhere else, try this (this will adapt the cell references of the formula for the previous line to the next one-- just like copy/pasting it using Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V):

```
Sheets("sheet name").cells(NextFreeLine-1, 6).Copy
Sheets("sheet name").cells(NextFreeLine, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
```

Comment: Using your Method 1, wouldn't the OP lose any relative cell references as they relate to the row number within the formula?

Comment: You are right, that just occurred to me, too. We don't know what formula he is trying to copy but your assumption that they may somehow be referencing the other cells in the same line is fair. ;-) edited to recommend method 2.

Comment: If you change the property to `.FormulaR1C1` you can make a cloned copy and it will retain any relative/absolute cell references.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using to put into 'the next available row' would have been nice to see but perhaps you can translate this for your own purposes.

```
'put the newval into the next available cell in column A
cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).offset(1, 0) = newval
'copy the formula in column F to the new row
cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).offset(-1, 5).resize(2, 1).filldown
```

Your value goes into the next available row based on column A. The same column is used in much the same manner but offset up a row and resized to two rows in height before executing the fill down command.